# SQL Statuswise Data Select

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Student_No Modified_ON StatusID 
1234       1 Nov 2017   1       
1234       2 Nov 2017   2       
1235       1 Nov 2017   1        
1235       2 Nov 2017   1        
1235       3 Nov 2017   3   
1236       1 Nov 2017   1
1236       3 Nov 2017   2   
1237       3 Nov 2017   3
```

Expected O/p

```
Student_No Modified_ON StatusID 
1234       2 Nov 2017   2  
1236       3 Nov 2017   2
```

I need all latest (highest date)records where StatusID changes from 1 to 2

Comment: sorry I dont get it. can you explain why ``1234 2 Nov 2017 2`` is  the expected o/p?  where does it change from 1 to 3?

Comment: Yes... I need latest record whose status changed from 1 to 2... By mistake I typed 1 to 3.

Comment: Student_No Modified_ON StatusID 
1234       1 Nov 2017   1       
1234       2 Nov 2017   2       
1235       1 Nov 2017   1        
1235       2 Nov 2017   1        
1235       3 Nov 2017   3

Answer (score 0):

According your output you will need to `group by` with `max` function aggregation

```
SELECT Student_No,
       MAX(Modified_ON) [Modified_ON],
       MAX(StatusID) [StatusID]
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM <TABLE>
    WHERE StatusID = 2
          AND Student_No IN
    (
        SELECT Student_No
        FROM <TABLE>
        WHERE StatusID = 1
    )
) AA
GROUP BY Student_No;
```

Above SQL Script will return

```
Student_No  Modified_ON StatusID
1234        2 Nov 2017  2
1236        3 Nov 2017  2
```

Comment: It is not becoz it will also select where status is not 2 when there is single record.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with multiple querys and a if-else clause:

```
SELECT (
CASE WHEN ( (
  SELECT StatusID
  FROM students
  ORDER BY `Modified_ON`  DESC
  LIMIT 1
  ) = 1)
THEN  
  ( SELECT Student_No
  FROM students
  ORDER BY `Modified_ON`  DESC
  LIMIT 1 )
  ELSE (
  SELECT Student_No
  FROM students
      WHERE StatusID = 2 and Student_No in (
      SELECT Student_No
      FROM students
      WHERE StatusID = 1 
  )
  ORDER BY `Modified_ON`  DESC LIMIT 1
  ) 
  END )
FROM students
```

see mysql-fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c601d9/2

Comment: It is not useful

Comment: please explain why. it delivers the expected result

Comment: I checked it but I need lastest record by date, if its status is 1 then only need to select

Comment: I've code also but not properly formatted so Stackflow not allowing it. You can consider below logic which I've implemented. 

Logic: Created SR Number over unique number,Status_Id and Order by Date Desc

Select ROw_Number and Rank_Number  to above selected data with desired where clause

Answer (score 0):

Using window functions we get the expected result

```
;With cte(Student_No, Modified_ON, StatusID )
AS
(
SELECT 1234,'1 Nov 2017',   1 UNION ALL       
SELECT 1234,'2 Nov 2017',   2 UNION ALL      
SELECT 1235,'1 Nov 2017',   1 UNION ALL       
SELECT 1235,'2 Nov 2017',   1 UNION ALL       
SELECT 1235,'3 Nov 2017',   3 UNION ALL  
SELECT 1236,'1 Nov 2017',   1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1236,'3 Nov 2017',   2 UNION ALL  
SELECT 1237,'3 Nov 2017',   3
)
    SELECT Student_no, 
       Modified_on, 
       Statusid 
FROM   (SELECT Student_no, 
               Max(Modified_on) 
                 OVER( 
                   partition BY Student_no 
                   ORDER BY Modified_on DESC) Modified_ON, 
               Statusid 
        FROM   
                   Cte 
                WHERE  Statusid IN( 1, 2 ))dt2 
WHERE  dt2.Statusid = 2
```

Result

```
Student_no  Modified_on Statusid
----------------------------------
1234        2 Nov 2017   2
1236        3 Nov 2017   2
```

Answer (score 0):

I've code also but not properly formatted so Stackflow not allowing it. You can consider below logic which I've implemented.

Logic: Created SR Number over unique number,Status_Id and Order by Date Desc

Select ROw_Number and Rank_Number  to above selected data with desired where clause